# Calling Puppet from bash script

Tags: bash, shell, puppet

I'm trying to call puppet from a bash script and whilst it works, it causes my script to end prematurely.

```
#!/bin/bash

...

function runPuppetLocally()
{
    echo "...running Puppet locally"
    exec puppet agent --test
    echo "Puppet complete"
}
runPuppetLocally
```

I presume Puppet is issuing an exit or something similar which causes my script to end. Is there a means by which I can call it without it terminating my script?

Answer (score 5):

Why do you use `exec`? Read `help exec`:

> Replace the shell with the given command.

Your script is *replaced* with the puppet. If you do not want it to replace your shell, call it normally, i.e.

```
puppet agent --test
```

Comment: It was an attempt to solve the problem. Calling it without exec has the same effect.